# Get a 'survfit' object which will be the same size than the original data in case of ties? (survival, R)

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survival

I want the survival probability estimated by Kaplan-Meier estimator for each individual of my dataframe.
The  `survfit(Surv(.))` function calculates the survival probability for each unique time ordered by decreasing order.

**What would be an elegant way of getting the survival probability for each individual from a `survfit` object?**

```
library(survival)
data = data.frame(cbind(id = 1:10, 
            time = c(2,3,4,5,2,3,8,9,10,11), 
            status = c(1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)))
survfit(Surv(data$time, data$status)~1)$surv
 # 0.9000 0.7875 0.7875 0.6300 0.6300 0.4200 0.4200 0.0000
survfit(Surv(data$time, data$status)~1)$time
 #  2  3  4  5  8  9 10 11
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the results in a data.frame and then just merge it back in

```
merge(data, 
   with(survfit(Surv(data$time, data$status)~1), data.frame(time, surv))
)
```

Here I just use `with()` to easily extract both columns from the survfit result.

Comment: It's working. I had a problem at the beginning when the name of the variable in the survift were pasted from elsewhere and were not found in the data. 
I also tried to make a loop but it was less elegant than just doing a merge :-)